# Moving from one view to another using sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm very new to sencha touch and ive having difficulty in moving in moving from one view to another when i click the add button in my mainview in my practice application.ive tried searching for errors in my console panel but Chrome just shows and empty console. I'm sorry if this seems like a noob query but any help is gratefully accepted.

**MainView.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    requires: [
        'Ext.navigation.Bar',
        'Ext.Button'
    ],

    config: {
        itemId: 'MainView',
        navigationBar: {
            docked: 'top',
            itemId: 'navbar',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    align: 'right',
                    itemId: 'addButton',
                    iconAlign: 'center',
                    iconCls: 'add'
                }
            ]
        }
    }

});
```

**AddForm.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AddForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.DatePicker',
        'Ext.picker.Date',
        'Ext.Button'
    ],

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                itemId: 'myForm',
                title: 'Insert Data',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        label: 'ID',
                        name: 'id',
                        required: true
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        label: 'Name',
                        name: 'username',
                        required: true,
                        autoCapitalize: true
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                        label: 'Date Of Birth',
                        labelWrap: true,
                        placeHolder: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'saveButton',
                margin: 10,
                ui: 'confirm',
                text: 'SAVE'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'declineButton',
                margin: 10,
                ui: 'decline',
                text: 'DELETE'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

**FirstControl.js(Controller)**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.FirstControl', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            MainView: 'mainview',
            addButton: 'mainview #addButton'
        },

        control: {
            "mainview #addButton": {
                tap: 'add'
            }
        }
    },

    add: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        console.log('inside the add function');
        this.getMainView().push({
            xtype:'AddForm',
            title:'Insert'
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

forgot to add the alias:'field'

Answer (score 0):

Change your add function in FirstControl.js(Controller file) file to below.

`add: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        console.log('inside the add function');
        this.getMainView().push(Ext.create('MyApp.view.AddForm'));
    }`

It should work.